# libpng warning: Incompatible libpng version in application and library

Tags: linux, opensuse, software-installation, libraries, r

```
libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.2.39
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.4.0
libpng warning: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
```

---

`Rgooglemaps` depends on `png`: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/index.html
Attempting to run the `RgoogleMaps` code through `Qt` resulted in the above errors.

---

```
linux-y3pi: # zypper what-provides libpng

Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82' appears to outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
S | Name        | Type    | Version      | Arch   | Repository                         
--+-------------+---------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------
v | libpng12-0  | package | 1.2.46-7.3.1 | x86_64 | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82
i | libpng12-0  | package | 1.2.44-2.1   | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3-Oss                  
i | libpng12-0  | package | 1.2.44-2.1   | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3 11.3-1.82            
v | libpng12-0  | package | 1.2.46-7.3.1 | i586   | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82
v | libpng12-0  | package | 1.2.44-2.1   | i586   | openSUSE-11.3-Oss                  
v | libpng14-14 | package | 1.4.3-3.3.1  | x86_64 | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82
i | libpng14-14 | package | 1.4.3-2.1    | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3-Oss                  
i | libpng14-14 | package | 1.4.3-2.1    | x86_64 | openSUSE-11.3 11.3-1.82            
v | libpng14-14 | package | 1.4.3-3.3.1  | i586   | Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82
v | libpng14-14 | package | 1.4.3-2.1    | i586   | openSUSE-11.3-Oss
```

Running the `Qt` executable with `ldd` results in:

---

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/abc/qtR> ldd qtR

        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5312c000)
        libR.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f1cf838b000)
        libRblas.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so (0x00007f1cf815f000)
        libRlapack.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so (0x00007f1cf7de5000)
        libRcpp.so => /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.so (0x00007f1cf7b94000)
        libRInside.so => /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.so (0x00007f1cf797f000)
        libQtWebKit.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0x00007f1cf61ab000)
        libQtSvg.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f1cf5f4b000)
        libQtXml.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f1cf5cff000)
        libQtGui.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f1cf4f82000)
        libQtNetwork.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f1cf4c44000)
        libQtCore.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f1cf4761000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1cf4544000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1cf423a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1cf3fe3000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1cf3dcd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1cf3a6d000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f1cf3826000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1cf361d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1cf3419000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f1cf320b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1cf899a000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f1cf2f25000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1cf2d1a000)
        libphonon.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libphonon.so.4 (0x00007f1cf2aba000)
        libQtDBus.so.4 => /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib/libQtDBus.so.4 (0x00007f1cf2832000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f1cf25fb000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f1cf2372000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1cf215c000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1cf1f49000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1cf1c09000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1cf1a04000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1cf1720000)
        libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f1cf1517000)
        libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f1cf12fa000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f1cf10a5000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f1cf0e7b000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1cf0c5e000)
        libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007f1cf0a30000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f1cf082b000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1cf0627000)
```

---

R info:

```
> sessionInfo ()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
```

---

uname -a

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> uname -a && cat /etc/issue
Linux linux-y3pi 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Welcome to openSUSE 11.3 "Teal" - Kernel \r (\l).
```

[image]

**The deinstallation of libpng12 says that'll have to install a 32 bit version of `R-patched`!**

**What to do?**

Answer (score 1):

Havent been using suse for a *really* long time, but in general I'd try these steps:

- Ensure that not only the library for libpng 1.4 is installed, but all headers as well. This might be in a separate development package or similar.
- Remove the R library, and reinstall it from source. It should compile those sources using the headers installed on your system, hopefully the 1.4 version. Have a close look at the compilation commands and see whether there is some information as to the libpng version used.
- There might be an executable called `libpng-config` somewhere on your path. It probably is a symlink, and changing that symlink might change the version of libpng used for builds.
- Also have a look at where the `/usr/lib*/libpng.so` symlink points to. It could well be that the `qtR` binary loads that library dynamically by name, without including the ABI version number in that name.